# SharePoint DateTime Control Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimecontrol

I have SharePoint `DateTime` control and I want to execute some code whenever the user changes the date using `JQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Thanks

Comment: add an ``onchange`` event on  the control